# how can I show that this function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

$x_1, x_2 > 0$

$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{x_1^3x_2}$

Is this function  convex?

I think it is because Hessian matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{12}{x_1^5x_2} & \frac{3}{x_1^4x_2^2} \\ \frac{3}{x_1^4x_2^2} & \frac{2}{x_1^3x_2^3}\end{pmatrix}$$

How do i show that the matrix is positive? multiply it by vector a^T and a isn't working..

Thanks!

can i just say its positive cause every element is positive?
[image]

Comment: Do you know the connection between positive definiteness and the determinants of the principal minors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix#Characterizations

Comment: My fault, that applies only to nondecreasing positive convex functions.

Comment: so the matrix is positive because the 1x1 matrix is positive?

Comment: Not just the $1\times 1$ matrix, you need to look at both the upper left $1\times 1$ and the full matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion.

Comment: By the way, just because a matrix has all non-negative entries, it doesn't mean that the matrix is positive semi-definite (consider for instance the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$). The 'non-negative matrix' definition you showed is something different to the definition of 'positive semi-definite'.

Comment: can u please show me the calculation that needs to be done in order to show that the matrix is positive definite? (or non negative).. i really don't understand what it is write in the wiki page.. please

Comment: You need to show that the upper left $1\times 1$ submatrix and the upper left $2\times 2$ submatrix (which is just the whole matrix) both have positive determinant. Are you able to calculate the determinants of these and show that they're positive? Note also that the determinant of a $1\times 1$ matrix is just the element itself.

Comment: now i udnerstand what to do.. i did it thanks.. and no, I've no idea what the guy told me in the last post.. I've no idea..